# Firebase iOS GoogleSignIn Transitions without clicking default signin button

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

i'm implementing the Firebase iOS Swift signin using the tutorial at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

I've selected the option to use Google's custom button: add a View and set its custom class to GIDSignInButton.
When I build & run, my signin view controller shows the rendered Google default button fine, but it immediately transitions to the Google web signin in the simulator, it doesn't wait for a user click.

The Google view's "interaction" attribute is set to the default "User Interaction Enabled."  I've also tried cleaning the project, relaunching Xcode, deleting the app from the simulator and "Reset Content & Settings..." in the simulator.
I've also gone in to the Simulator "Settings" for "Safari and done a "Clear History and Website Data".  Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.  Hadn't noticed a previous SO post on this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but rather redirection to Google Sign In page i received blank screen: [image]

There is pitfall in tutorial at step 7, where it suggest to(optionally) sign in viewDidLoad method:[image]

just comment or remove line:`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()` and you'll get on click redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Without code sample is hard to tell what went wrong. I have implemented Google Sign In myself lately. But I use my own custom button. Here is my code:

```
class SignInVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}

@IBAction func googleSignInButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}

extension SignInVC: GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

// [START headless_google_auth]
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("README: Error when sign in with Google")
        return
    }

    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!, accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)

    //this method will finish login to Firebase

    FirebaseLogin.sharedInstance.firebaseAuthentication(credential)
}
```